# Assign a different class to shopify-section depending on page

Tags: shopify, liquid

In a blog section on my site I specify a class to be added onto `shopify-section` in my schema code. Here's a snapshot of that code (I'll not post it all):

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Blog",
    "class": "band band--tint",
    "settings": [
```

That works great however in my `product.liquid` the layout is slightly different and I don't want the `band--tint` class on that page.

Is there a way I can target the handle/template so I can remove this class just for that layout?

Comment: create a custom template and handle the class by the {{ template.name }} what ever you wanr

Comment: Do you mean just duplicate the file, give it a different class and load that template on the product page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create an alternate template to modify HTML.

> Creating an alternate template allows you to modify the way content is
>   shown on your online store, but only for the products, collections,
>   blogs, and other pages that you apply the alternate template to. For
>   example, you can create an alternate product template that has no add
>   to cart button, and apply it only to products that are not for sale.
>   Or, you can create an alternate page template that doesn’t include a
>   header, and apply it to a selection of your store’s pages.

[Source](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/store/create-alternate-templates)

Comment: I thought about doing that. Just cloning the template, amending that classes and loading that onto the product page instead. Wasn't sure if it'd be a pain to maintain 2 templates that do the same job though for the sake of a class?

Comment: You can try to abstract the template logic into a block. So the only dynamic part is that block and not the entire template.

Comment: I think I might be best off created 2 sections and maybe put the content in a snippet which is used in each template so it's not a duplicated big chunk of code. I think the problem is I'm trying to manipulate the classes on a shopify generated div which is tricky!